# Show GPU memory usage and utilization for a slurm job

Tags: gpu, slurm

I am using slurm to access GPU resources. Is it possible to show GPU usage for a running slurm job? Just like using `nvidia-smi` in a normal interactive shell.

Answer (score 5):

you can use ssh to login your job's node. Then use nvidia-smi. It works for me.
For example, I use squeue check my job xxxxxx is current running at node x-x-x. Then I use ssh x-x-x to access to that node. After that, you can use nvidia-smi to check the usage of GPUs.

Comment: I am getting this error message: **Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error**

Comment: This means your cudatoolkit is not installed. Recommend to install through anaconda

Comment: what x-x-x stand for exactly? is the PARTITION column in the output from squeue command?

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the users, don't have the permission to compute-node, I mean `ssh node-1`

Here is the way in slurm,

1. Check your jobid:

```bash
squeue -u <your_username>
```

and you will get the jobid for that.

2. srun within your jobid with nvidia-smi

```bash
srun --jobid=123456 nvidia-smi
```

Comment: I get  an error message like this when trying to use `srun` to run nvidia-smi. `srun: Job 123456 step creation temporarily disabled, retrying`. So far, can't find a solution to this message. How do you resolve this?

Comment: `123456` should be your jobid, I just write a random number here...

Comment: I did use the specific job that was running the interactive session and that was the message I got. My suspicion is that the interactive session ONLY allows me to run that one shell that was provisioned by slurm and thus when I tried to run `srun` for nvidia-smi on the same job, it gets stuck.

Comment: I see. Then the reason is mostly because the admin of slurm disables the srun in the existing batch.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to launch your application manually in jupyter and access the terminal shell in jupyter.